# not able to load redirected URL(Login URL) in WKwebview

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, saml, wkwebview

I am integrating SAML based authentication in iOS application via integrating `WkWebview`.

when i load the `URL`(A to fetch the secure content) it redirects to another(authentication URL) which is trying to load in to `webview`.
but it does not show anything in `webview`.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
class SamlLoginScreenViewController: UIViewController,WKUIDelegate  {


    @IBOutlet weak var wv_saml: WKWebView!
    var webView: WKWebView!


    override func loadView() {

        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myURL = URL(string:"https URL")//it redirect to another //URL e.g. www.login.com( which does not get loaded)
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code -

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let myURL = URL(string:"put Your link here") 
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self as? WKNavigationDelegate
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }

    //MARK: Hide status bar
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool{
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: I am having the same issue. I am loading the URL in WKWebView, but i am not able to. How ever it is loading with SFSafariViewController. Not sure what is the issue

Answer (score 0):

You set zero frame to webView (`webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)`), so you can't see it. Try to set correct frame to webView and add it as subview, for example:

```
webView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds, configuration: webConfiguration)
view.addSubview(webView)
```

Comment: I am having the same issue. I am loading the URL in WKWebView, but i am not able to. How ever it is loading with SFSafariViewController.  Frame i am setting correctly.Not sure what is the issue.